# How to invoke NATS cli from a docker container running in detached mode

Tags: docker, containers, command-line-interface, nats.io, nats-jetstream

I am new to NATS and decided to start playing with it using docker.

After pulling the official NATS image from docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/_/nats) I ran it as a container in detached mode using the following command:

```
docker container run --name my-nats -p 4222:4222 -d nats
```

Now if I want to access the NATS cli using the `docker container exec` command, how do I do it?

I tried several different ways all resulting in errors:

**Attempt 1**:

```
docker exec -ti my-nats bash
```

resulted in the following error:

```
... starting container process caused: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

**Attempt 2**:

```
docker exec -ti my-nats sh
```

resulted in the following error:

```
... starting container process caused: exec: "sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

**Attempt 3**:

```
docker exec -ti my-nats /bin/bash
```

resulted in the following error:

```
... starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown
```

**Attempt 4**:

```
docker exec -ti my-nats /bin/sh
```

resulted in the following error:

```
... starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

I could not find a lot of information specific to the NATS cli, so I tried all these options I saw online regarding other apps. I guess NATS has a different command to open the cli, but I just could not find it.
I even tried escaping the backslashes which resulted in more or less the same errors.

I would deeply appreciate any help or guidance with discovering a way to work it out and access my container's cli.

Comment: It's possible that image just doesn't have a shell.  If the program is in a compiled language (C, C++, Rust, Go) and the final image is built `FROM scratch` then it's possible for the image to contain _only_ the application and absolutely nothing else at all.  As you're describing this, though, it doesn't especially seem like a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

It is based on alpine, use `ash`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried replacing `bash` with `ash` but got the same result, any idea how to continue from here?

Comment: Finally worked by me, I used alpine tag: docker run --rm  -it  nats:2.8.4-alpine3.15 sh